# webView persists in other fragments

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-webview

I have an app with bottom navigation bar made with Android Studio. I want to display a webView only in the first fragment, but when I switch to other fragments using bar's buttons, the webView doesn't stop and persists on the background of the other fragments. This is my code:

```
package com.myapp.application;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.myapp.application.R;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        WebView webView = v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        return v;
    }
}
```

And this is `fragment_home.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing same with BottomNavigationView, it works.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    final BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your fragment

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    webView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    webView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}
```